# ElasticSearch for Time Series Data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am evaluating a number of different NoSQL databases to store time series JSON data.  ElasticSearch has been very interesting due to the query engine, I just don't know how well it is suited to storing time series data.

The data is composed of various metrics and stats collected at various intervals from devices.  Each piece of data is a JSON object.  I expect to collect around 12GB/day, but only need to keep the data in ES for 180 days.

Would ElasticSearch be a good fit for this data vs MongoDB or Hbase?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37133862/3524828

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using time based indices, for instance an index a day, together with the index-template feature and an alias to query all indices at once there could be a good match. Still there are so many factors that you have to take into account like:
- type of queries
- Structure of the document and query requirements over this structure.
- Amount of reads versus writes
- Availability, backups, monitoring
- etc

Not an easy question to answer with yes or no, I am afraid you have to do more research yourself before you are really say that it is the best tool for the job.

Comment: Is there any limit to how many indexes you can have?  If I wanted to have an index for each metric for each day, is that going to be too much for ES to handle?

Comment: Yes, the amount of indices per machine/node can be to much. You have to configure the amount of chards wise. You can also think about using types instead of indices.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 21):

You can read up on ElasticSearch time-series use-case example [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/case-study/data-dog/).

But I think columnar databases are a better fit for your requirements.

My understanding is that ElasticSearch works best when your queries return a small subset of results, and it caches such parameters to be used later. If same parameters are used in queries again, it can use these cached results together in union, hence returning results really fast. But in time series data, you generally need to aggregate data, which means you will be traversing a lot of rows and columns together. Such behavior is quite structured and is easy to model, in which case there does not seem to be a reason why ElasticSearch should perform better than columnar databases. On the other hand, it may provide ease of use, less tuning, etc all of which may make it more preferable.

Columnar databases generally provide a more efficient data structure for time series data. If your query structures are known well in advance, then you can use Cassandra. Beware that if your queries request without using the primary key, Cassandra will not be performant. You may need to create different tables with the same data for different queries, as its read speed is dependent on the way it writes to disk. You need to learn its intricacies, a time-series example is [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra).

Another columnar database that you can try is the columnar extension provided for Postgresql. Considering that your max db size will be about 180 * 12 = 2.16 TB, this method should work perfectly, and may actually be your best option. You can also expect some significant size compression of about 3x. You can learn more about it [here](http://citusdata.github.io/cstore_fdw/).

Comment: Great info, thanks for the response!

Comment: Amazon Redshift too - a postgres like column oriented db